# How to test Asp.net WebApplication in different internet speed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

how is it possible to test a web application developed in VS 2008, in different internet speed connections?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 4):

For a quick test of slow (modem) speeds, you can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and enable the *Simulate Modem Speeds* option - found in the Rules -> Performance menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle your bandwith with tools like [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle your bandwidth but this still won't give you an accurate idea of how fast it will be for other users. There are other factors, like where it's hosted for example.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have use this program http://xat.com/wo/index.html and is very good.